# Python - How to combine multiple re.sub functions into a single function?

Tags: python, regex

```
for i in (f):
    r = re.sub('.*\.f', '.wiki [href*=""], .f', i)
    s = re.sub('width', 'min-width', i)
    t = re.sub('height:40px;', '', i)

    outp.append(r)
    outp.append(s)
    outp.append(t)
```

As you can see, I have 3 lines of regex that work individually but it doesn't work like how I'd want to because they are appended 3 times so I need to combine them and append it once.

Comment: You also can use a single line: `re.sub('height:40px;', '', re.sub('width', 'min-width', re.sub('.*\.f', '.wiki [href*=""], .f', i)))`. Just replace each *i* with another `re.sub()`. The inner-most `re.sub()` function will be evaluated first. This is the same as the answer given by Cantfindname.

Comment: *"they are appended 3 times"* - because **that's exactly what you ask it to do**. Have you considered *reading the code* before asking a question?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
for i in (f):
    r = re.sub('.*\.f', '.wiki [href*=""], .f', i)
    s = re.sub('width', 'min-width', r)
    t = re.sub('height:40px;', '', s)

    outp.append(t)
```